# Is this battery right one for STM32F411RE

Tags: microcontroller, batteries

https://robocraze.com/products/3-7v-1000mah-li-ion-battery?currency=INR&variant=40193362231449&https://robocraze.com/?utm_source=googleads

I am using STM32F411RE for one of my projects and wanted to know if this battery is the right fit for it.

Here is the datasheet.

https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f411re.pdf

Comment: It depends what you want to do with it, for how long, and what are you going to put between battery and STM32 - because no lithium battery can be directly connected to STM32.

Comment: What sort of regulator do you plan to use?

Comment: Uhmm i have no idea what a regulator is.. i am a newbie when it comes to electronics..

Comment: Anyways, what i want to do is, I have written a RTOS for STM32F411 and plan to design a collision detection system using it. I will be connecting the board to an Arduino which will be connected to a motor driver. I will be disconnecting the STM32 board from my laptop and will need external power. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Yuv - Implementing battery use with a MCU will require extra circuity for controlled charge / discharge of the battery and voltage stabilization. Since you wont be using regulators and such (I assume) the easiest way would be just use a 5V external battery bank and USB cable to your STM board (assuming you are not using a discrete IC).

Comment: @Yuv A "regulator" is a voltage regulator, like a "buck converter" or a very low quiescent current and low dropout linear voltage regulator, to reduce your battery/cell voltage from  3.4-4.2V down to about 3.3V (or even 3V, which should be fine), as your STM32 can't work at more than 3.6V.  The lithium cell needs a lithium cell charger circuit and a small lithium battery cell protection circuit, or a small charging circuit with protection built-in, to prevent overcharge, over-discharge and too much charging current.

Comment: I think that will do! Thanks guys!!